# testing the difference between two meta-analytic effect-sizes

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, group-differences

I would like to know if it is possible to statistically test for difference between effect sizes (Hedges g in this case)

For example, let's say I have run a random effects meta-analysis on $20$ studies. In $10$ of these studies the treatment is solely on women and in $10$ the treatment is solely on men. Subgroup analyses show that the summary effect size for women is $g = 0.7,\, 95\% \text{ CI } [0.65-0.75]$ and for men it is $ g = 0.6 \,, 95\% \text{ CI } [0.55-0.65 ] $.

Is there a valid way to test if the effect is stronger in women compared to men?

Comment: You could certainly bootstrap.  I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: The answer is yes, it is called meta-regression. Do you want to do some research on that and then edit your post if you cannot achieve what you desire?

Comment: If you are using R, see here: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates You can also easily compute the Wald-type test by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a rather standard moderator analysis using the analog to the ANOVA procedure originally developed by Hedges' and Olkin. This method is similar to a one-way ANOVA or in this case a t-test but produces a Q statistic that is chi-square distributed. This can be done in R using the metafor package. For Stata, SPSS, or SAS, there are macros http://mason.gmu.edu/~dwilsonb/home.html
(note that I am the author of these macros).

Note that your mean effects size may be a bit different under this model as the default is to use a common estimate of the random effects variance component (tau^2). I believe that metafor has an option for estimating separate tau^2 for each group. It is also worth noting that the Cochrane Handbook simply recommends examining the 95% confidence intervals to see if they overlap. While reasonable, this will not always agree with the Q-test, particularly if the standard errors for the two means are substantially different.

Comment: The link in @wolfgang's comment above explains how to estimate with different amounts of heterogeneity using metafor.

Comment: Meta-regression and the analog to the ANOVA will produce the same result just different output.